# How do I access struct fields that are part of a vector.Vector?

Tags: go

I am looking for help understanding how to access struct fields that are inside a container.vector.Vector.

The following code:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "container/vector"

func main() {
    type Hdr struct {
        H string
    }
    type Blk struct {
        B string
    }

    a := new(vector.Vector)

    a.Push(Hdr{"Header_1"})
    a.Push(Blk{"Block_1"})

    for i := 0; i < a.Len(); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("a.At(%d) == %+v\n", i, a.At(i))
        x := a.At(i)
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", x.H)
    }
}
```

Produces the error `prog.go:22: x.H undefined (type interface { } has no field or method H)`

removing lines 21 and 22 produces:

```
a.At(0) == {H:Header_1}
a.At(1) == {B:Block_1}
```

So, how exactly does one access 'H' or 'B'? It seems like I need to convert those interfaces to structs, but... I dunno. I'm at a loss.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The `container/vector` package has been deprecated since 2011-09-01 and isn't part of the standard library anymore. Use slices and [SliceTricks](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Go [type switch](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Switch_statements) or [type assertion](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Type_assertions) to distinguish between the `Hdr` and `Blk` types. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "container/vector"
)

func main() {
    type Hdr struct {
        H string
    }
    type Blk struct {
        B string
    }

    a := new(vector.Vector)

    a.Push(Hdr{"Header_1"})
    a.Push(Blk{"Block_1"})

    for i := 0; i < a.Len(); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("a.At(%d) == %+v\n", i, a.At(i))
        x := a.At(i)
        switch x := x.(type) {
        case Hdr:
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", x.H)
        case Blk:
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", x.B)
        }
    }
}
```

However, effective the [weekly.2011-10-18](http://weekly.golang.org/doc/devel/weekly.html#2011-10-18) release:

> The container/vector package has been deleted. Slices are better:
>   [SliceTricks](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks).

Therefore, for the latest releases,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    type Hdr struct {
        H string
    }
    type Blk struct {
        B string
    }

    var a []interface{}

    a = append(a, Hdr{"Header_1"})
    a = append(a, Blk{"Block_1"})

    for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("a[%d]) == %+v\n", i, a[i])
        x := a[i]
        switch x := x.(type) {
        case Hdr:
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", x.H)
        case Blk:
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", x.B)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ack! I'm still getting used to the comment system.

Comment: @mtw: If this was the answer to your question, please click on the checkmark symbol under the vote number on the answer =)

Comment: @Tom: done! For some reason I couldn't mark the answer as accepted due to low reputation. Had to wait for a few hours. Thanks again, peterSO.

Comment: @mtw: And please edit your question to remove the "[SOLVED]" from the title and remove the solution code.  I'd edit it myself, but the code edited into the question isn't quite the same as what's in the accepted answer, and I don't know how to resolve that.

Comment: @KeithThompson. OK no problem. What's the accepted way to include the "solution" in this post? Should I add it as a comment to the question?

Comment: @mtw: If this answer is the solution, there's no need to add it anywhere else.  Add a comment if you have information that's not already part of the answer (but comments don't necessarily stay around).

Comment: @Keith Thomson: What mtw did was fine; he was properly documenting his continued efforts to answer his question. Read his original question. my answer, and his revised question. The "SOLVED" annotation was unnecessary. I've revised my answer to include the essential information that you persuaded mtw to delete.

Comment: @peterSO: I only meant to suggest deleting from the question information that was already in the answer.  I don't know Go well enough to tell what that is.  Sorry for any confusion.  (But I'd say the answer is the best place for the additional information anyway.)